# Why is the induced voltage due to the current of the phase conductor wrapped around the shield not included in the inducedvoltage calculation formula?

Tags: voltage, cables, shield, sheathing

Why is the induced voltage due to the current of the phase conductor wrapped around the shield not included in the voltage calculation formula induced by the shield/sheath in the three-phase coaxial cable?

As shown in the equation below, the voltage induced in the a-phase shield/sheath surrounding the a-phase conductor is only due to the b-phase and c-phase conductor current.

Why is there no induced voltage due to a-phase conductor current?

[image]

[image]

The picture is from http://www.jicable.org/2007/Actes/Session_B9/JIC07_B97.pdf.

And IEEE-575-2014 AnnexD also converted the expression using the 120 degree rotation operator a, but the result is the same expression.

https://dokumen.tips/documents/575-2014-ieee-guide-for-bonding-shields-and-sheaths-of-single-conductor-power.html

The equation of the a-phase shield/sheath induced voltage above is converted to the following.

[image]

Obviously, there is only the induced voltage due to the b-phase conductor current and the c-phase conductor current. Why was the induced voltage due to the a-phase conductor current not considered?

Comment: Coaxial cable is not 3 phase cable neither in anyone's ability to procure it nor, in any technical meaning of the word "axial". Maybe tri-axial cable? I think your opening paragraph needs some extra words. For instance, is it the induced voltage that is wrapped around the shield or, is it the phase current that is wrapped around the shield. I couldn't get myself past this barrier.